# How to create .DBF file without .DBT file in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I want to create .DBF file which is having many fields with datatype MEMO. So its generating .DBT file. I want to create only .DBF file. What is the alternate of MEMO datatype? Which datatype should I use to store VarChar(Max) data in .DBF file?